# Is there any way to override the getter value in swagger codegen?

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I have my .yaml file as follows: (Just a partial definition)

```
schemas:
    BaseResponse:
      type: object
      required:
        - success
      properties:
        success:
          type: boolean
          default: "false"
```

When I run `java -DdebugModels -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l java` 
I see the following for the success field:

```
  "baseName" : "success",
  "getter" : "isSuccess",
  "setter" : "setSuccess",
  "datatype" : "Boolean",
  "datatypeWithEnum" : "Boolean",
  "name" : "success",
  "defaultValue" : "false",
```

Is there any way I can override what the getter field name is generated as?
I'm using swagger codegen 3.0.19 and the yaml file is written using openapi: 3.0.0

Comment: have you found an solution for this question?